# Azure Portal doesn't see DevOps organization [account problems?]

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I'm having trouble connecting my Azure Web App to my Azure DevOps organization.
I somehow managed to do it for one Web App (by selecting creating a new 'DevOps Project') but now struggle at setting a new WebApp to link to that same DevOps pipeline. (The goal is to have a two stages delivery pipeline, which requires 2 webapps: one for QA, the other for Prod).

When creating a new WebApp, I go to Deployment Center > Azure Repos > Azure Pipelines (Preview) and get the following error message : "You do not have any valid Azure DevOps organization".

Any idea how to make that work? Note: I tried creating WebApps with same resource group and same App Service Plan and doesn't work.

Thanks a lot for any help.
Best
Lucas

UPDATE: The issue here is having Azure Portal "see" the DevOps organization.
Seems to be an account issue: you know how one has two options in account?

[image]

Pretty sure it has something to do with the Azure Portal and DevOps being on different account "directories": "Default Directory" VS "Microsoft Account". But still can't explain the behaviour....

Comment: There are specific steps for the process you are trying to create. You need to use stages. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/environments?view=vsts

Comment: Hi Rthomas529, that part was not an issue. The stages are there. The issue is to connect the prod stage to its Web App. And ,Azure Portal just won't recognize my DevOps organization-

Comment: @Lucas any update on that issue. I ran into same one.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same "You do not have any valid Azure DevOps organization" message. I solved it by going to the Visual Studio Marketplace and enabling billing for our visualstudio.com repo for Microsoft-hosted CI/CD. Some documentation says DevOps (Azure Pipelines) is free for 5 users, I'm guessing we didn't qualify because we have 6 active users in our Azure Devops (visualstudio.com) repo. (We recently had to break out the credit card to enable a 6th team member.)

Here are the steps I used to get to the marketplace and enable billing:

1. In the Azure Portal, click "All services" then search for "devops".
2. Click "Azure DevOps organizations"
3. Our visualstudio.com (aka Azure DevOps, the service formerly known as VSTS) project repo was displayed in the results.  Click on it.
4. A summary display appeared with "Setings | Remove billing | Set up billing   | Connect AAD ..." along the top. In lower right of the summary area, click "All settings =>". An "Organization settings" blade (column) displays on the right.
5. In the "Organization settings" blade, click "Azure Pipelines". In our case, the display showed "MICROSOFT-HOSTED CI/CD" with "0 Edit" beneath, and SELF-HOSTED CI/CD with "1 Edit" beneath. The Self-Hosting doesn't apply to us, so...
6. Click "Edit" for the Microsoft hosted CI/CD item.
7. You will be taken to marketplace.visualstudio.com with "Microsoft-hosted CI/CD" displayed on the left and a screen where you can select the number of "Paid parallel jobs". In our case, we use a 3rd party service for our Microsoft licensing, so I wasn't able to see what the Total cost would be. But I chose 1 parallel job and continued through the process. Once I'd enabled billing, I was then able to go back into the Azure Portal and (after refresh) make it into the process of setting up a build pipeline as per the various videos and documentation.

As is so often the case with Microsoft, the initial  "You do not have any valid Azure DevOps organization" message was not helpful, the process nothing like the smoke-and-mirror demos, and wording like "free for 5 users" misleading.

Hopefully the above will work as it did for me and save others some time.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to create your private extension and want to test it.
You should share it with the corresponding organization:

[image]

after that, you will be able to install it successfully

Comment: This worked for me too. The error message is very misleading, as it seems that it should have said "you are not a member or owner of any organisations that have access to this extension", or similar.