# Azure Devops seemingly not connected to Azure Portal on same account

Tags: azure, azure-devops

created a Azure Devops Account + Organization, but when I log into the portal with the same account, it does not see my organization and thus I can't do anything like setting up a Azure AD.  Has anyone seen this issue before?

Looks like [this person](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784356/azure-portal-doesnt-see-devops-organization-account-problems) had the same problem but did not get a resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I have not ran into that issue. My understanding of the process is;

- If you want to link DevOps to your Azure AD you should log into
  DevOps with an existing Azure AD Account.
- If you create a new account or sign in with an account not tied
  to an Azure AD tenant on DevOps that creates a new Azure AD tenant.

Hope this helps